# Supremum over unitary group action

Tags: group-theory, matrices, functional-analysis, lie-groups, computational-mathematics

Let $A$ and $B$ are two given Hermitian operators on matrix algebra $M_n(\mathbb{C})$. $A$ is positive semi-definite with unit trace. I want to know the general method for calculating the following quantity
\begin{equation}
\sup_{U\in \mathcal{U}_n} |Tr(UAU^*B)|,
\end{equation}
where $Tr$ is the trace operation, $\mathcal{U}_n$ is the group of $n \times n$ unitary matrices. Is there a general method (algorithmic?) for finding such quantities?

Moreover, is there a similar method if we try to calculate

\begin{equation}
\sup_{X\in Gl_n(\mathbb{C})} \frac{|Tr(XAX^*B)|}{Tr(XAX^*)}
\end{equation}

Partial work: I know, this is unbounded with respect to $n$. However I want to see the above quantities  for a fixed $n>2$, where $A$ and $B$ are known.

Comment: With regards to the second supremum, how can you vary $n$ without varying $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić I guess I did not understand your comment. $A$ and $B$ are fixed and so is the dimension $n$.  $X$ is varying over $Gl_n(\mathbb{C})$. I expect the answer to be $n$ dependent.

Comment: @rsg: Do you mean $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb C)$?

Comment: I was wondering what you meant by that quantity being "unbounded with respect to $n$." I guess you're looking for an upper bound of the form $f(n,\|A\|,\|B\|)$?

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić yes. I guess, it will come as you have mentioned. My approach was to exploit Lie algebra structure of unitary group. I could not make any progress in that respect.